# Why is the following SCM not markovian?

Tags: causality

Right now I am dealing with Causal Inference and Structural Causal Models(SCMs). Judea Pearl talks about Markovian and non-markovian SCMs. A SCM is Markovian if P(u_1,u_2,...,u_n) = P(u_1)*...*P(u_n) where u_i are the exogenous variables.

Why is a SCM which induces the following graph not markovian?

u1 -> x1 -> x2 <- u2 and  x2 <- u3 -> x1

For me it looks like u1, u2 and u3 are mutually independent but I know from my lecture that a SCM which induces such a graph is not markovian, so there is something wrong here. u1, u2, and u3 can't be mutually independent then but I don't see why.